# Animate part of the image

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a splash in my application. And everything was fine before customer asked me to implement different splash animations, like slide transitions in PowerPoint (Dissolve, Checkerboard, Blinds, Shred, Doors and etc.) You can have a look at them [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nE7PJK3JTwA)

For example, for checkerboard I can cut splash image into one set of parts and use default android xml animations. For blinds or doors I will need two more different sets of splash image parts. This approach will require different layout for each animation. So the size of the application will grow dramatically and complexity of splash will increase too.

Is there a way how to do that without cutting splash image into parts? Can I animate different parts of one image separately?

Comment: one way would be to use a canvas...

Comment: I agree with Th0rndike

Comment: If your target is API >= HONEYCOMB then you can use RenderScript. It would give you the best performance.

Comment: Isn't RenderScript deprected already? https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/m194NFf_ZqA/discussion

Comment: I think implementing all animations by hand when using canvas is not an easier task.

Comment: @vasart I didn't say it was easier, i said it's one way of doing it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Th0rndike proposed we created [CanvasAnimation](https://github.com/vasart/CanvasAnimationView) project on github, which uses `Canvas` to draw animations. There are two examples with cells and ellipse animations.

[image: cells animation example]

Comment: Hey @vasart , Can you please share how you implemented checkerboard transition.